# jQuery document on('click') event preventing form on('submit') event

Tags: jquery, onclick, event-handling, jquery-events, onsubmit

I have an HTML div `img_div` which is receiving dynamically generated content including a form. The form has an `input type="file"` and `input type="submit"`.

I wrote a jQuery function `showImg()` which dynamically populates `img_div` and overrides the submit event for the form, which prevents the page refresh and appends files uploaded by the form.

`showImg()` works perfectly on its own. However, I want `img_div` to disappear when the user clicks anywhere else on the page, so I created a `$(document).click()` event handler to hide the div when the user clicks anywhere else. This event also works, except when I implement it, the page now refreshes when I submit my form in `img_div`.

To be clear, if I disable the `$(document).click()` event, the form appends the image without refreshing the page. If I enable `$(document).click()` event, the form refreshes the page and navigates to a page just displaying the loaded image.

Why is the `$(document).click()` event handler preventing the `on('submit', 'form')` event handler from firing? How do I get the two event handlers to both fire when the form is submitted? I tried using `event.stopPropagation()` on the `input type="submit"` in my form, but it had no effect.

Here is the `img_div` html:

```
<div id="img_div" class="pop_up_menu" style="position:absolute; left:'. (135) .'px; background-color:#FFF; display:none; min-width:800px"></div>
```

And here are the JS functions:

```
$(document).click(function( event ) {
    if (event.target.id != 'img_div' && $(event.target).parents('#img_div').length == 0) {
        var tag = 'div';
        var element_class = 'pop_up_menu';
        var div_list = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        for(var i=0;i<div_list.length;i++)
        {
            if(div_list[i].className == element_class)
            {
                var el_id = '#'+div_list[i].id;
                $(el_id).off();
                div_list[i].innerHTML="";
                div_list[i].style.display = 'none'; 
            }
        }
    } else {
    }
});

function showImg(event, divID, category, id)
{
    var y = event.pageY;
    var x = event.pageX;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById(divID).style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById(divID).style.top = y+'px';
            document.getElementById(divID).style.left = x+'px';
            document.getElementById(divID).style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
        }
    }
    
    var url = "/rtd/plugins/includes/image_popup.php?category="+category;
    url += "&id="+id;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    $('img_div').off();
    $('#img_div').on('click', 'input', function( event ){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#img_div').on('submit', 'form', function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var rowid = 'row_'+Date.now();
        var rowpointer = '#'+rowid;
        var form_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var form_pointer = '#'+form_id;
        var form = $(form_pointer)[0];
        var formData = $(form_pointer).serialize();
        var action_url = $(form_pointer).attr('action');
        
        var fileData = new FormData(this);
        
        var ajIMAGE = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: action_url,
                data: fileData, 
                contentType: false, 
                processData: false
            })
        ajIMAGE.done(function ( data ) {
            $("#image_table").append('<tr><td id="'+rowid+'">'+data+'</td></tr>');
            $("#noimage").hide();
            $(form_pointer).trigger('reset');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: where is your submit button? In HTML I can't find it.